# Extensions of a projective special linear group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Is it possible to classify groups that can be decomposed as a semidirect product $G=\mathrm{PSL}_2(q) \rtimes \langle t\rangle$, such that $t\in G$ has order $4$ and $Z(G)=\langle t^2\rangle$?

Comment: Apart from $q = 2,3$ the group $PSL_2(q)$ is simple, so it has no center of order 2 generated by $t^2$.

Comment: I was confused by the formulation too, but $t^2$ is not supposed to belong to $PSL_2$. So the group can be redefined: let $u$ be an automorphism of order 2 of $PSL_2(q)$, consider the semidirect product of $PSL_2(q)$ with a cyclic group of order 4 acting by $u$.

Comment: What is the question? You provide a description of your group as a semidirect product, this seems fine.

Comment: In fact our group is $(PSL_2(q)\times A).<t>$  where A is an abeluan group of order 2 and $t^2\in A$

Comment: I wish know if G is isomohic to any known group.

Comment: Apart from recognizing them for a few small values of $q$, I doubt so. Of course this depends on what you mean by "known". It's a bit like asking whether $10^q+7$ is a "known number".

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood the question, the situation is this: For $q$ is an odd square, there are two such groups, depending on which automorphism of order 2 you choose -- they'll have form $2.PGL_2(q)$ or $2.P\Sigma L_2(q)$. If $q$ is an even square or an odd non-square, then there will be one such group; if $q$ is an even non-square, then there will be no such group.

Comment: @YCor I don't really understand your problem with this question. It seems meaningful to ask for a classification of the isomorphism classes of groups with the specified structure, which Nick Gill has now given. Of course the element $t^2$ is not really playing any role here, and is just causing a distraction.

Comment: @DerekHolt your problem, as stated in your comment, is perfectly clear. It was not in the original question, nor in the comment by the OP.

Comment: @Nick Thank you very much for your useful answer

Comment: @NickGill Now that we all understand the question, perhaps you should answer it. The question would be more interesting if you replaced the condition $Z(G) = \langle t^2 \rangle$ by $|Z(G)| = 2$, because then I think you get an extra example when $q$ is an odd square, in which the automorphism induced on ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ is the product of a diagonal and a field automorphism.

Comment: @DerekHolt, thanks for your comment. I've done as you suggested. I will add a little note to describe the example that you pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

These groups can be written as subgroups of $Aut(PSL_2(q)) \times C_4$. Note that $Aut(PSL_2(q)=P\Gamma L_2(q)$ and, writing $q=p^f$,  that 
$$
P\Gamma L_2(q)/ PSL_2(q) \cong  \begin{cases}
C_2 \times C_f, & \textrm{ if $q$ is odd};\\
C_f, & \textrm{ if $q$ is even}. 
\end{cases}
$$
These facts are enough to work out that your group $G$ will be generated by $PSL_2(q) \times \{1\}$ and an element $(\phi, g)$ where $\phi$ is an outer involutory automorphism of $PSL_2(q)$ and $g$ generates $C_4$. Now the possibilities for $G$ just depend on what the possibilities for $\phi$ are.

1. **If $q$ is an odd square**, then you can choose $\phi$ to be either diagonal or a field automorphism; in the former case, the group $G$ has structure $2.PGL_2(q)$; in the latter the group $G$ is a subgroup of $2.P\Sigma L_2(q)$.
2. **If $q$ is an even square**, then $\phi$ must be a field automorphism, and the group $G$ is a subgroup of $2.P\Sigma L_2(q)$.
3. **If $q$ is an odd non-square**, then $\phi$ must be diagonal, and the group $G$ has structure $2.PGL_2(q)$.
4. **If $q$ is an even non-square**, then no such group exists (since there is no choice of $\phi$ available).

Note that in the first case -- $q$ an odd square -- you might be wondering why $\phi$ cannot be a product of a field and a diagonal automorphism. The reason is that there is no such product of order $2$ -- the extension of $PSL_2(q)$ that you obtain by adjoining such an automorphism is non-split.
In this case, though, you **can** choose $\phi$ to have order $4$ in which case (as Derek Holt points out in his comment above), the group generated by $PSL_2(q)\times\{1\}$ and $(\phi, g)$ satisfies all of the properties that you require, except that $Z(G)$ is not equal to $\langle t^2\rangle$, although it is of order $2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the exact answers. I have one more question. If G=2.PGL(2,q), can we say that $G$ is isomorphic to $GL(2,q)/Z $

Comment: What if $Z$ in your question? ${\rm GL}(2,q)/Z({\rm GL}(2,q)) = {\rm PGL}(2,q)$ by definition.

Comment: Z is a dpsubgroup of Z(GL(2,q)) of index 2 in it

Comment: I don't know what a dpsubgroup is, but I think the answer to your question is yes if and only if $q \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

Comment: Is it true that the non-split  extension of Z_2 by PGL(2,q) is isomorphic to GL(2,q)/Z , where Z is a subgroup of Z(GL(2,q)) of index 2 in it?

Comment: I just answered that!

Comment: May I know that why in the case  q≡3mod4. The answer is not yes?